How to Extend Token Expiration Time in JetAppointments Plugin?
I'm using the JetAppointments plugin for booking functionality on my WordPress website. However, I've noticed that the token generated by JetAppointments is only valid for a few minutes before it expires, requiring users to reauthenticate or regenerate the token.
I would like to extend the lifespan of the token to avoid interruptions for users during their session. After some research, I couldn't find any specific settings within the plugin to configure the token expiration time.
Any guidance on how to increase the token validity period or handle this more gracefully would be greatly appreciated!
